# How can I antialias circle contained in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, graphics, antialiasing

I'm trying to produce an antialiased circle in in pygame `1.9.1release`, so I do not have access to `pygame.gfxdraw`, nor do I really feel like using this submodule since it is clearly marked as being experimental.

This having been said, I would like to produce an antialiased circle, so I was wondering if there was a way to achieve this using pygame's ability to reference pixels in `numpy` arrays.

Below is an example of such a circle.  The pickled numpy array containing the circle as a 3D array (with the 3rd dimension represeting RGB values) can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6160029/pgcirc.pickle).

[image: Aliased circle drawn by pygame]

**My question is as follows:** How can I smooth the edges of the circle I have draw, preferably using numpy?

Comment: I don't have experience with pygame.gfxdraw, but one anti-aliasing trick (eg. OpenGL) is to blend the line on to the background. Another idea is use pre-generated (smooth) circle images as textures.

Comment: @M-V, Your comment has me a bit confused -- I don't have access to pygame.gfxdraw and I'm specifically asking how to achieve this *without* that module.  As it stands, the idea of blending the line to the background sounds like a very good option -- how should I go about doing this?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post. But I think you found a solution. What I was suggesting may require changing too many things, but maybe you could do some research on opengl antialiasing. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512456/how-to-draw-smooth-line-with-antialias) is one related SO post.

Comment: @M-V I suspected as much ;).  Thanks for the link!