# Smooth edges for a square in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/openglexamples/ in this example of Spinning Square you can notice that the edges of the square in the image are not-smooth. How can I fix this?

Comment: There are big number of anti aliasing techniques out there: FXAA, MLAA, MLAA, GPAA, etc. On a simple test like this the most simple solution is probably just to create a multisampled framebuffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these functions before drawing:

```
glEnable( GL_LINE_SMOOTH );
glEnable( GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH );
glHint( GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST );
glHint( GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST );
```

or you can use this before drawing:

```
 Gl.glShadeModel(Gl.GL_SMOOTH);
 Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
 Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_BLEND);
 Gl.glBlendFunc(Gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, Gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
 Gl.glHint(Gl.GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, Gl.GL_DONT_CARE);
```

See which one makes a better look for you.

Similar questions was asked before about drawing lines:

[How to draw smooth line with antialias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512456/how-to-draw-smooth-line-with-antialias)

Answer (score 2):

The effect you see is called Aliasing, and can be resolved using an antialiasing techneque.

The are multiple antialiasing tecneques possible but by far the most common at the moment is MSAA (multisample antialiasing) https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling.
MSAA is quick and easy from a developer's point of view as support is provided in modern drivers and just needs to be enabled at application startup. It does however come at a runtime performance cost.