# How to create a cylinder or some flash effect between two points?

Tags: three.js

As simple as it sounds these proving more difficult then I thought. 
1) I tried Lee Stemkoski's particle examples.
https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/
But there seemt to be no clear way of providing source and target 
2) Also the THREEx extension for laser is there
http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2014/04/29/beautiful-dynamic-laser-beams-for-your-space-game-with-threex-dot-laser-game-extension-for-three-dot-js/
But I can not change the color. My background is white so I would liek a colored laser.
Also the glow is only when it interesects the object.

Comment: There is code on how to create a cylinder between two points here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30644582/1980846

Comment: Thank you gaitat that is the best answer so far.

Comment: you could give me some points on that answer.