# how to draw smooth line without MSAA

Tags: opengl-es, line, smoothing

i am figuring out how to draw smooth line using OpenGL ES.
i have done with part of this task as the following steps:

1. make **two triangles** to form the line.
2. **make its border transparent**.

you can refere to this link [old solutioin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512456/how-to-draw-smooth-line-in-opengl-with-antialiasing) to see the main idea.

But i still get **one problem** to solve: **how to smooth both end of the line**? 
you can see the current situation by click the image description.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5sds.png)
In the image, you can clearly see the left end of line has **sawtooth**.

can any one give me a solution? i will thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Add more triangles to form an end-cap, make them transparent in the same way you blend the edges.